# How can I install python modules to an EMR and they work on PySpark scripts? (not noteboks)

Tags: pyspark, amazon-emr, python-packaging

I have an EMR that have mixed Python/PySpark steps and I'm migrating the Python ones to PySpark, in one of the migrated steps I need to use some Python packages (scipy and sklearn),
I can work with them in JupyterNotebooks [**Install Python libraries on a running cluster with EMR Notebooks**](https://aws.amazon.com/es/blogs/big-data/install-python-libraries-on-a-running-cluster-with-emr-notebooks/) but when I run the EMR using an Lambda function these steps fails. I've googled and find that using bootstrap script can helps but I use this but EMR steps don't work:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo pip3 install scipy sklearn
exit 0
```

There is someway to install packages in the EMR cluster or in each step? I'm loss on this.

Comment: what does the error state?

Comment: dont use sudo in the bootstraps script and also you can remove exit 0 just keep pip3 command

Comment: What version of EMR are you running?